# Shopify Schema, section settings work in <style> tag, but block settings doesn't

Tags: css, shopify, schema, block, sections

I ran into a weird problem while modifying a section with a few blocks. Basically, I wanted to add a new block to an already existing section. I've already set up the schema, and this part works as expected. But the problem is, I can not use the block settings inside a < style> or {% style %} tag. But the settings work fine in the HTML lines. Note: section settings work in style tag, just the block setting doesn't.

**Example 1 (doesn't work):**

```
<style>
    .custom_box {
        background: {{block.settings.box_color_from_block}};
    }
</style>
```

**Example 2 (works):**

```
<div class="custom_box" style="background: {{block.settings.box_color_from_block}};"> </div>
```

**Example 3(works):**

```
<style>
    .custom_box {
        background: {{section.settings.box_color_from_section}};
    }
</style>
```

Note: I have a color picker inside the block I am creating with the id "box_color_from_block", and when it wasn't working, I added a color picker in the section with the id "box_color_from_section" to test. And I found the above result.

I searched on google and found a similar StackOverflow post from 2 years ago. There, somebody suggested adding the input in the section instead of the block. Sure enough, it works, but it's not useable for me. I specifically need example 1 to work.

The setup is that I am generating a < div> using a {% for %} loop for every product in a collection. Thus, the method in example 2 becomes unsuitable. And every < div> needs to have a different background color. There'll be like 5/6 color pickers(will vary depending on the collection). Thus, adding them to the section will make the already crowded section even more filled up. Hence, I want to add the color pickers inside the block settings, which is pretty empty.

Thanks a whole bunch in advance for reading through, and I'd be really grateful for an answer. My main issue is, that I'm puzzled by the situation. I don't really know what's happening and why.

Comment: Block schema  work under for loop

Comment: block related settings are not available outside the loop, so use it inline style or place a style tag within the block loop.

Comment: Yes, but the divs need to have different background colors. If I use the background color inside the for loop, then all the divs become the same color. So, I'm planning on using nth-child to apply different colors in the style tag.

Comment: when you place it into block, then it applied to all so set the color to desired block and another choose the color none or transparent

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I didn't know block settings don't work outside the block loop. Now I get why section settings work. And the inline styling work, because it is inside the for loop. 

so, even though it doesn't solve my problem, I know now that it isn't solvable, and it gave me other ideas how I can do it. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, in example 2 it works because you are using **block.settings.box_color_from_block** inside the div which is inside a liquid for loop.

In your for loop you are looping though **section.blocks** to get each block data :

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  <div class="custom_box" style="background: {{block.settings.box_color_from_block}};"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

in your **Example 1** , you are not looping through liquid for loop in your CSS, thus **{{block}}** is undefined.

---

**Solution :**

You need 2 for loops, one for the HTML and one for the CSS.

In the HTML loop you create your div with a unique ID for each block using **{{block.id}}** .

In the second for loop in the CSS you use the **div ID** to customize it using **block settings**

```
<style>
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  #custom_box_{{block.id}}{
    background: {{block.settings.box_color_from_block}}
  }
{% endfor %}
</style>

{% for block in section.blocks %}
 <div id="custom_box_{{block.id}}" class="custom_box"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, {{block.id}} was the solution. I didn't know it back then, therefore I couldn't separate the divs, id attribute wouldn't work on the HTML, and all of the divs would have the same class names. therefore, I couldn't select each div individually in a reasonable way. But following the comments on the post, I searched on google, and learnt about {{block.id}}. That solved pretty much my whole issue. And solution is pretty close to the one you suggested. Thank you very much.